# HBase "Failed to identify the fs of dir"

Tags: java, hbase, warnings

I'm developing **HBase Client** with **Java**.

Here, my developing environment:

> HBase 1.0.1.1 with standalone mode
>
> Java 1.7.0_85
>
> `test.jar` file which is tied all library files provided by HBase library. (by using fat jar)

And I compile java by using following command:

> javac -cp test.jar MYCODE.java
>
> java -cp ./*:. MYCODE

After that, It returns warning as follow:

```
WARN util.DynamicClassLoader: Failed to identify the fs of dir /tmp/hbase-{$userid}/hbase/lib, ignored
     java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: file
```

It works fine, but I want to remove that warning. Is there any suggestion for me?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: any news regarding the warning in question?

Comment: @user1455836 I just re-install hbase, and provblem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Hbase allows you to put additional dynamic classes in hdfs. It is looking for those classes but can not find any classes in you hbase.dynamic.hars.dir settings. It is a harnless error.

If you'd like to remedy the issue, you can ensure hbase.dynamic.jars.dir isn't set.

If you'd like to suppress the message, you'll need to set the log level for the logger org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader to ERROR.

Comment: Could you clarify 'not setting `hbase.dynamic.jars.dir`'? I don't have that property in any of my config files, most notablly `hdfs-site.xml`. But do I need to have the property with an empty value instead? `<property>
<name>hbase.dynamic.jars.dir</name>
<value></value>
</property>`